# Segmentaion fault vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

При использовании push_back в std::vector мне возвращается segmentation fault, вот код:

```
bool loadData(vector<Worker> &workers)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("count.dat", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) return false;

    int count;
    fread(&count, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    file = fopen("log.dat", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) return false;

    Worker* _workers = new Worker[count];
    fread(&_workers, sizeof(_workers), count, file);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        workers.push_back(_workers[i]);

    delete[] _workers;

    return true;
}
```

count - это количество элементов для массива _workers. Есть идеи?

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет ни одного std::vector. Что такое Worker, что такое workers (без подчёркивания)? Приведите [mcve], по вырванному из контекста куску ничего не понятно

Comment: Я привел код всей функции. В ней я считываю из бинарника количество элементов для динамического массива _workers, который затем инициализирую и заполняю при помощи указанной вами строки. Затем перед мной стоит задача перенести содержимое данного массива в вектор, делаю это при помощи функции push_back

Comment: По-прежнему непонятно, что такое workers на самом деле. Покажите, где, как и с какими параметрами вы вызываете функцию loadData

Comment: Ну и Worker вы тоже так и не показали (а тематика вопроса-дубликата намекает, что проблема может быть именно в Worker)

Comment: для сначала **не** размер указателя  `sizeof(_workers)` , а размер класса `sizeof(Worker)`. Ответ полный не получится, так как неизвестно как выглядит ваш класс. Во вторых, записывать данные на **место** локальной переменной `fread(&_workers` это **очень** плохая идея.